# Quebra de linha do select options que contenha um valor muito extenso

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

É possível quebrar a linha de um **option** muito extenso?

ex:

```html
<select>
  <option>texto muito extensp<br/>restante do texto</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Pode até existir uma forma, mas a solução de verdade é colocar um texto menor e NUNCA ter quebra de linha na opção.

Comment: com certeza seria o ideal, mas sabe como são os clientes, pediram um texto monstruoso no option

Comment: Com option não existe, o que você fazer, é utilizar isso com li, e muita elaboração em CSS, eu até conseguiria fazer, primeiro veja se é uma necessidade importante. Pois  pode reduzir a fonte, como pode fazer somente o drop abrir extenso, definindo a largura... como é feito no autocomplete de endereço do googlemap. Há muitas formas

Comment: Bom, vou te passar um exemplo aqui:
**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/f6udze8q/** Este é o link da [**documentação**](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js). E este é o link do [**projeto**](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js).

Comment: É falha dos desenvolvedores e gerentes de projeto não insistirem e educarem os clientes e usuários sobre tecnologia. Aí ficamos criando funções de formatação em tempo de digitação cheias de pontos falhos que limitam o livre uso do usuário por perfumaria do cliente. Quem entende de tecnologia tem que se impor perante quem não entende.

Comment: Aumenta o tamanho dos _option_ usando _css_. De qualquer das formas isso não assenta no _select_, se for para passar  opções com tamanhos como este porquê não usar _radio_ ? Tu como programador deves saber dizer aos clientes o que melhor encaixa.

Comment: Se você colocar o seu texto no title da opção não resolve ?

Coloca a descrição reduzida, mas o texto grande no title, então aparece a dica flutuante ao passar o mouse, não sei se funciona, mas vale testar.

Comment: Obrigado o auxílio de todos!

Comment: Concordo quando dizem que devemos orientar o cliente, mas muitos devem saber que nem sempre isso é possível, sempre procuro passar idéias de boas práticas para projetos, porém muitos não aceitam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, isto não é possível de se fazer. No entanto podes sempre optar por utilizar [esta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384605/3624981) alternativa de adicionar um `title` ao `option`:

```html
<select>
    <option value="1" title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see &quot;This is my lengthy...&quot; on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!">This is my lengthy...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: É uma boa ideia, exceto que se o valor persistir em banco, deverá ser utilizado o atributo title do elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está a resposta para o seu problema:

```
 <section style="background-color:rgb(237.247.249);">
    <h2>Seleção com texto longo abaixo:</h2>
    <select name="select_this" id="testselectset">
        <option value="">Selecione abaixo...</option>
        <option value="01">Opção 1</option>
        <option value="02">Opção 2</option>
        <option value="03">Opção 3 - Muitos softwares de publicação e editores de páginas na internet agora usam Lorem Ipsum como texto-modelo padrão, e uma rápida busca por 'lorem ipsum' mostra vários websites ainda em sua fase de construção. </option>
        <option value="04">Opção 4</option>
        <option value="05">Opção 5 - o contrário do que se acredita, Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico. Com mais de 2000 anos, suas raízes podem ser encontradas em uma obra de literatura latina clássica datada de 45 AC. Richard McClintock, um professor de latim do Hampden-Sydney College na Virginia, pesquisou uma das mais obscuras palavras em latim, consectetur, oriunda de uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum, e, procurando por entre citações da palavra na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua indubitável origem.</option>
        <option value="06">Opção 6</option>
        <option value="07">Opção 7</option>
        <option value="08">Opção 8</option>
    </select>
    </section>
```

o código JavaScript:

```
$(function(){

    $("#testselectset").selectBoxIt({
        theme: "default",
        defaultText: "Selecione abaixo...",
        autoWidth: false
    });
    $("#testselectset").change(function(){
        alert("Item selecionado: "+this.value);
    });

});
```

A folha de estilo:

```
.selectboxit-container .selectboxit, .selectboxit-container .selectboxit-options {
  width: 200px; /* Width of the dropdown button */
  border-radius:0;
  max-height:240px;
}

.selectboxit-options .selectboxit-option .selectboxit-option-anchor {
    white-space: normal;
    min-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
}
.selectboxit-option a {
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

[**Clique aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/f6udze8q/) para ver o exemplo executando.

Este é o link da [**documentação**](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js). E este é o link do [**projeto**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/f6udze8q/).